# How to return unsliced values?

Tags: javascript

For example,

```
var str = "Hello"; 
console.log(str.slice(-1));
```

returns value sliced off, "o" — but how would I return the unsliced value, in this case, "Hell"?

Comment: `"Hello".slice(0, -1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use two parameters on `slice()` to define the start and length of the slice.

```js
var str = "Hello"; 
console.log(str.slice(0,4));
```

If you don't want to use a static value but just slice off the last letter, you can use `str.length -1` as a dynamic value for the slice length.

```js
var str = "Hello"; 
console.log(str.slice(0,str.length-1));
```

Or even simply use `-1`:

```js
var str = "Hello"; 
console.log(str.slice(0,-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not only use negative index for `begin` parameter but also you can use to `end` parameter. Thus, this will do your task:

```
console.log(str.slice(0,-1)); // start from 0, end from -1
```

Answer (score 0):

slice from 0 to -1

```js
var str = "Hello"; 
console.log(str.slice(0,-1));
```